# how does the copy cp command differentiate between the ESP and root partition?

Tags: linux, command-line, filesystems

the boot directory exist on both the ESP(sda1) and root(sda5) partition.

when i use this sample command to copy vmlinuz and initrd files:

sudo cp -a initrd.img-4.15.0-43-generic /boot

i was able to get the system to boot and thought i had copied the file to the ESP. i also checked the root partition after using the command and confirmed it does not exist.

however, after a few days, i discovered the files had appeared in the boot directory of the root partition.

before that, i had also manually moved the files to the boot directory of the root partition using a file manager(dolphin) but was unable to get the system to boot.

so i would like to ask what is the command to copy files to the ESP partition, and the command to copy the same file to the root partition? basically, i would like to know how the linux system differentiate between the ESP and root partition for the same sets of command, i.e, cp, mkdir..etc

thanks

Comment: What is ESP and which distribution are you talking about?

Comment: @UVV The ESP is the "EFI system partition".

Comment: On Linux or any UNIX you can mount file systems to any directory, so without further information we don't know where `/boot` is located. What does `mount` show?

Comment: Can you also provide the output of `lsblk`, so that we can see how your disks are organized?